# A type-safe cast in TypeScript with a discrminiating union (like C++'s dynamic_cast)

Tags: typescript

I'm looking for a readable way to do a type-safe cast in TypeScript. I have an object with a discriminating union, and I have an unclear syntax for casting.

```
enum my_type {
    drag = 'drag',
    std = 'std',
}

interface base {
    type: my_type
}

interface drag {
    type: my_type.drag
}
interface std {
    type: my_type.std
}

type all = drag | std

function test_drag(obj: all) {
    let obj_drag: drag|null = obj.type == my_type.drag ? obj : null
    if (!obj_drag) {
        console.log("It's not a drag")
        return
    }
    console.log("It's a drag")
}

test_drag({type: my_type.drag}) // yes
test_drag({type: my_type.std}) // no
test_drag({type: 'drag'} as any) // yes
```

I'm interested in a cleaner way of doing     `let obj_drag: drag|null = obj.type == my_type.drag ? obj : null`
A generic function that takes a type parameter would be good, but I don't know how to get the syntax right. That is, I want a function that look something like this:

```
function dynamic_cast<DiscriminatingType>(obj): ObjectType
```

So I can call it something like this:

```
let obj_drag = dynamic_cast<my_type.drag>(obj)
let obj_std = dynamic_cast<my_type.std>(obj)
```

Is this type of function possible, or something that is close to it? Mainly I want something that is readable, and preferably without having to specify both the discriminant and the resulting type.

---

@jcalz Providers this generic approach.

```
function dynamicCastO<T, K extends keyof T, V extends T[K] & (string | number | boolean)>(
    obj: T, k: K, v: V) {
    return obj[k] === v ? obj as Extract<T, Record<K, V>> : null;
}
```

So I'm wondering if I can eliminate the need to pass `type`. In my attempt below the return type isn't of the desired type.

```
function dynamicCast<K, T extends { type: K }>(
    obj: T, v: K) {
    return obj.type === v ? obj : null;
}
```

Comment: The static type system is [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) when TS code is emitted as JS. Both of those lines would produce JS like `let obj_drag = dynamic_cast(obj)` and `let obj_std = dynamic_cast(obj)`; there's no way to tell at runtime which type was specified.  If you make it like `dynamic_cast(obj, my_type.drag)` that could work, but only for `all` subtypes.  Or `dynamic_cast(obj, "type", my_type.drag)` for generic discriminated unions. This is no simpler than `obj.type == my_type.drag ? obj : null`... is such an answer acceptable to you?

Comment: Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/lWY92W).  I don't think I'd bother with such a solution.

Comment: That looks quite close, and is generic. Is it possible to convert that to work for a specific type as well, or to just assume there is a "type" value. I've tried, but having trouble getting it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way of writing a function that can discriminate a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions) is this:

```
const discriminateUnion = <K extends PropertyKey>(
    discriminantKey: K
) => <T extends Record<K, string | number | boolean>, V extends T[K]>(
    obj: T, discriminantValue: V
) => obj[discriminantKey] === discriminantValue ? obj as Extract<T, Record<K, V>> : null;

const dynamicCast = discriminateUnion("type");
```

Here `discriminateUnion` takes a single parameter corresponding to the *discriminant* key of the discriminated union.  In your case, it's `"type"`.  It then returns another function which accepts an object of the discriminated union type, and a discriminant value to check.  If the object's discriminant property matches that value, then it returns the object narrowed to the relevant member of the union.  Otherwise it returns `null`.

Discriminant properties need to be comparable by `===` for this to work, so I constrained them to `string | number | boolean`.  If you have some other unit discriminant like `null` or `undefined` you can add that in.  The return type, `Extract<T, Record<K, V>>` uses built in [utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) to pull out the member of the `T` union whose property at key `K` is of value `V`.  There may be edge cases here; if your discriminant is optional, for example, you might need to do `Extract<T, Partial<Record<K, V>>>` or something for it to work.

Let's try it.  I'm going to change the types to conform to standard TypeScript naming conventions (captialization and camel case stuff) and add a little structure to your union members to show that the discrimination has tangible results:

```
enum MyType {
    DRAG = 'drag',
    STD = 'std',
}

interface Base {
    type: MyType
}

interface Drag {
    type: MyType.DRAG
    dragProp: string;
}
interface Std {
    type: MyType.STD
    stdProp: string;
}

type All = Drag | Std
```

Then the implementation of `testDrag()` would use `dynamicCast` like this:

```
function testDrag(obj: All) {
    let objDrag = dynamicCast(obj, MyType.DRAG);
    if (!objDrag) {
        console.log("It's not a drag")
        return
    }
    console.log("It's a drag, dragProp is " + objDrag.dragProp.toUpperCase())
}
```

And your tests behave as expected:

```
testDrag({ type: MyType.DRAG, dragProp: "hello" }) // It's a drag, dragProp is HELLO
testDrag({ type: MyType.STD, stdProp: "goodbye" }) // It's not a drag
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngFTgB2FA3gKCjqARAJQEEBxKAXigHIATAJwEMBzKgGm1wGUE8LqBnAC402mAL6ZMASxCDgdAGYMAxmgBCDfmiy4oglMABcsRAfGSZcxSrR5GTDBxz7Ux+ElQA6QqSdR6zAAKdAD2yMZCdDJMANzmlvJKqlCcwo66LkYmHsCe3Hh+QjTBYRGCUSCx5piZUEQANvV8dsxQAD4pwpKYyiEgQv5S-MpREDIMcgCqIFJ9fAA8ANJQwAAeciA0-FAlqHT6i8BwAHwAFH40QyNSYyAMsodwxouYAJQUx1DzCCvroFtQAjAXp0GhLVhQSLRdpQcAQABG8hh8JCIXqwHuxwhADVfhsAQgANqLAC6Zz8IXhACtjAgIZdhqNxrJsQx6mAsti3h8oJSqYSGddbvdBI8SRRyJRBUy7iy2RyoAB+XnUqCaKAAUXWjGUgm+EKBILBixxx0+xnAjTiPT6AxocDuY2UAGFNII+NKbuMpjM+qcAESZf2va0KMAgXWzEB6YBCFpMU584wNervHS4dHuvnxj0OhhO11CRPUiHuAzeYgkEN+KQKKCnACE2fsab8ul6-TRuXqIQT-oAkoIqNsQCF3Qx-PZg23cHRgIIwHQQH4JO3bV3PD2+4Ph2rJ8x6fZdlAhlB-VAANQqqnxzwBJi7TyCEKTZB7QvAU6vV7VORx+ynOgegGG4pheD4JCHkEoThGeAAWwCNCE55iO8AD0aFQDu2wTveUEPjBJ7bAAEhqAAyZEAPI1LGgjxoBwGuNk5b5BCRS7MY-pMKiNDwnAwAoehmHYbCY57vemBAA)

Comment: This looks great! I'll test it out.